# Get old system config value on changed

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using admin_system_config_changed_section_[SECTION] to observe system config save action.
Is there a way to detect if a field has changed or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `isValueChanged()` from `vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\Value.php` file will be able to find if the particular **field** value has been changed or not.

To use this, apply tag named **backend_model** in the `module\etc\adminhtml\system.xml` for which field you would like to detect.

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="module" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>General</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::dimension_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General</label>                 
                <field id="dimension" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Dimension Text</label>
                    <comment>Dimension Text will display on the storefront.</comment>
                    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Backend\Dimension</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Dimension.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Backend;

class Dimension extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterSave()
    { 
        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {

            //To get old value use function  $this->getOldValue();

            //To get value  use function  $this->getValue();


        }
        return parent::afterSave();
    }


}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @DanielKratohvil, Can we save another config field's data inside this if loop?
 if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
}

Like this:
$scope = $this->getData('scope');
        $scopeId = $this->getData('scope_id');

        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
            $this->configWriter->save(
                self::TIMESTAMP_VALUE_FIELD,
                0,
                $scope,
                $scopeId
            );
        }

        return parent::afterSave();

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a good solution so made one myself.
I used a aroundSave() plugin on Magento\Config\Model\Config and took all the config settings before and after and checked the difference between these and added them in an array.

This is my code to achieve this:

Vendor\Module\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"
<type name="Magento\Config\Model\Config">
    <plugin name="name_of_plugin" 
      type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Config\AroundSaveConfig"/>
</type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Config\AroundSaveConfig.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Config;

class AroundSaveConfig
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * AroundSaveConfig constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }


    public function aroundSave(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        $section = $subject->getSection();
        $oldConfigs = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($section);
        //Proceed
        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $newConfigs = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($section);
        $changedValues = $this->checkDifference($oldConfigs, $newConfigs);

        $difference = $this->checkDifference($oldConfigs, $newConfigs);

        // Do whateever you want to do with the diff array which
        // contains both the old and new value of the array
    }


    public function checkDifference($array1, $array2)
    {
        foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                if (!isset($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                } elseif (!is_array($array2[$key])) {
                    $difference[$key] = $value;
                } else {
                    $new_diff = $this->checkDifference($value, $array2[$key]);
                    if ($new_diff != false) {
                        $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                    }
                }
            } elseif (!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value) {
                $difference[$key] = [$value, $array2[$key]];
            }
        }
        return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
    }
}
```

This worked for my purposes where I only wanted the changed values. Hope this help you or someone else.